# jquery based slideshow/transitions for HTML content

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Searching for rotators based on JQuery only finds the original rotator plugin and a bunch of photo galleries, which I don't want. Please suggest other rotators available. The rotator should be able to rotate HTML not just images (like the Glimmer tool, which can create JQuery/HTML code for rotating images).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use plug-in's? use this one liner (i just separated it into 3 lines for the sake of readability)

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g64rv/2/)

Your HTML should be something like this

#### HTML

```
<div class="yourContainer">
 <div>some html</div>
 <div>other html</div>
</div>
```

#### JS / jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('.yourContainer div:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.yourContainer :first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.yourContainer');}, 3000);
});
```

#### CSS (optional = makes transition smoother)

```
.yourContainer{ position:relative;}
.yourContainer div{ position:absolute; hight:300px; width:300px; background:red; }
```

Comment: Accepting this due to the simplicity presented. Specifically which part of the CSS makes the transition smoother because I'm seeing "coloring" effect during transition? I have a very subtle gray background on which I am about to put my divs and content.

Comment: Hey check out my sample, something isn't working right!
Here http://jsfiddle.net/9S9Qx/

Comment: See updated http://jsfiddle.net/9S9Qx/4/ please fix the CSS for the tags. Things i changed: attached jQuery 1.4.2, and added `position:absolute;` to the `.slide{}` and added speed to `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)
- [jQuery Flip Plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/)

You can even modify/customize these plugins to create the kind of effect you want.

Comment: Flip is a bit too fancy, but Cycle looks great. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

[link text](http://www.ndoherty.biz/tag/coda-slider/) is pretty cool.  They show an example from a [payroll company](http://www.paycepayroll.com/) in their demos that even degraded nicely without Javascript.

Comment: This one is great too and I'm definitely going to use it sometime in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple plugin called [Basic jQuery Slider](http://basic-slider.com). It's simple and clean and just does what it's supposed to. If you decide to use it and have any questions, just ask and I'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up using the [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/). [This one](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider) by Zurb is also great.